# Dislaying Image File in Container Exported From Video

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-image, flutter-video-player

Trying to export a frame from my video file, save it to an image file list, and then display it back when building my list of containers.

```
setState(() async{
      if (result!.files.isNotEmpty) {
        for (PlatformFile item in result.files) {
          videos.add(File(item.path!));
          var duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
          File image = await ExportVideoFrame.exportImageBySeconds(File(item.path!), duration, 0);
          videoThumbs.add(image);
          //tickets[widget.indexEvent].videos[i]
        }
      } else {}
    });
```

Then later in my page class I am trying to display it back for the user in a child of my container:

```
  Container(
            width: 220,
            height: 220,
            color: colorPrimary,
            child: Image.file(
            videoThumbs[i],
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
             ),
            ),
```

The code doesn't hard fail, and will build the apk, but when in the app, my thumbnail just says:
[image]

As you can see from my thumbnail, my list of photos and videos are building, but when it tries to loop through the videos and show a thumb, the array index is empty, I think? I believe I'm reading that error right.

I have seriously been at this for 2 weeks, and I could really use some help.

Comment: Add the snippet where the loop occurs to generate the value `i`. This error is common when you try to access an array with no size.

Answer (score -1):

in this list, Your data is not complete, on 2 last of your data is null.

use this:

```
    child:
videoThumbs[I] == null? const SizedBox():
Image.file(
                  videoThumbs[i],
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                 ),
```

Comment: After adding that extra line, it won't display any box now. Not even the error. Still builds fine, but just won't display anything. Any other suggestions?